# Word highlighting in vim (plugin)

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

Given a list of words, I want to highlight all those words in the current buffer.  I'm writing a vim plugin so I expect some yak shaving.

Is this possible in a sane manner?

Comment: Did you read `:help :match` and further?

Answer (score 2):

```
highlight LOL ctermbg=red
call matchadd("LOL", "this")
call matchadd("LOL", "little")
call matchadd("LOL", "light")
call matchadd("LOL", "of")
call matchadd("LOL", "mine")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is very easy to highlight multiple search terms, and quite sanely as described below.**

As a quick example, here is an example key binding to `F8` to **highlight all occurrences of the word under the cursor in the current buffer** taken from [Highlight all search pattern matches - Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches) (just enter `:set hls` to turn on search highlighting to cut to the chase):

```
:nnoremap <F8> :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>
```

So, I press my F8 button in my current buffer while sitting on the word `read` and this is what I get:

[image]

Expanding the search for multiple words, taken from [Search patterns - Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns), **Finding this *or* that**, search for words separated by an escaped pipe character, `\|`, like this:

```
/read\|execute\|readattr
```

And this is what is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a plugin that allows you to

- highlight the word under the cursor
- highlight a pattern specified on the command line
- give each new pattern a new color
- see the current highlighted patterns
- stop highlighting a pattern

see [mark.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666).

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom highlights (without affecting the current search pattern) is easy with the `matchadd()` / `matchdelete()` functions. The problem is in the *current buffer* requirement, because these functions are **window-local**.

For a quick and dirty, ad-hoc solution, this difference probably doesn't matter much, but for a plugin, you would need to handle (via `:autocmd`s) when another buffer is displayed in the current window (clearing the highlights then), and possibly also another window displaying the same buffer as the current one.